# XHR request to Firebase Functions stays hanging on Samsung Internet Browser 14

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, xmlhttprequest, samsung-internet

Our app uses the Firestore and Firebase Functions. To save an order, we call a [https callable Firebase Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) like this:

```
try {

  const setMealplanOrder = fn.httpsCallable("setMealplanOrder");
  await setMealplanOrder(newOrder);

  return true;

} catch (error) {
  console.log(" ~ file: saveOrder.tsx ~ line 158 ~ save ~ error", error)
  Sentry.captureMessage("Error saving order, possibly on Android?" + error);
}
```

It works and has worked on all devices, until a few days old Samsung update to Android 11 and Samsung internet 14. Now, the XHR request from `await setMealplanOrder(newOrder)` is just stuck. The console is empty, with no errors.

[image]

Any idea what could it be? Or how to debug this?

**Additional notes:**

- Interestingly, when I connect the phone to the app on a localhost, it works perfectly.
- When I try to fire the same request from a new clean app, it works. So the issue is probably caused in a combination with something else in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved: Firebase version issue!** The issue was in `firebase-messaging-sw.js` Service Worker, which we use for Firebase Cloud Messaging (push-notification). The version of the service worker was outdated.

```
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.2/firebase-app.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.2/firebase-messaging.js')

...
```

After updating both `npm i firebase@latest` and changing the version in the importScripts to `8.4.3`, it works as it should.